# Vedanta and Moksha

Tags: moksha, vedanta

Moksha is the important (and ultimate) goal of Hinduism. And whenever I think about it, Vedanta philosophy comes into picture. So, I think *there might be knowledge regarding Moksha included in Vedanta*.

- What is the Vedanta philosophy about Moksha?
- What Vedanta teaches and explains about Moksha?
- Does Vedanta give the way of Moksha? (How to?)

Answer (score 2):

Yudhisthira on Emancipation

> There are two well-known paths (for us), viz, the path of the Pitris
>   and the path of the gods. They that perform sacrifices go by the
>   Pitri-path, while they that are for salvation, go by the god-path. By
>   penances, by Brahmacharya, by study (of the Vedas), the great Rishis,
>   casting off their bodies, proceed to regions that are above the power
>   of death. Worldly enjoyments have been styled as bonds. They have also
>   been called action. Liberated from these two sins (viz, bonds and
>   action) one attains to the highest end. ….As a person on the hill-top
>   looketh down upon men on the plain below, so he that has got up on the
>   top of the mansion of knowledge, seeth people grieving for things that
>   do not call for grief. He, however, that is of foolish understanding,
>   does not see this. He who, casting his eyes on visible things, really
>   seeth them, is said to have eyes and understanding. The faculty called
>   understanding is so called because of the knowledge and comprehension
>   it gives of unknown and incomprehensible things. He who is acquainted
>   with the words of persons that are learned, that are of cleansed
>   souls, and that have attained to a state of Brahma, succeeds in
>   obtaining great honours. When one seeth creatures of infinite
>   diversity to be all one and the same to be but diversified emanations
>   from the same essence, one is then said to have attained Brahma. Those
>   who reach this high state of culture attain to that supreme and
>   blissful end, and not they who are without knowledge, or they who are
>   of little and narrow souls, or they who are bereft of understanding,
>   or they who are without penances. Indeed, everything rests on the
>   (cultivated) understanding!’

Mahabharata Santi Parva Section XVII

> Bhisma/Suka on emancipation
>
> Bhishma continued [Suka said],’..By knowledge, one attains to that
>   whither there is no occasion for grief; whither one becomes freed from
>   birth and death; whither one is not subject to decrepitude; whither
>   one transcends the state of conscious existence; whither is Brahma
>   which is Supreme, Unmanifest, immutable, ever-existent, imperceptible,
>   above the reach of pain, immortal, and transcending destruction;
>   whither all become freed from the influence of all pairs of opposites
>   (like pleasure and pain, etc), as also wish or purpose. Reaching that
>   stage, they cast equal eyes on everything, becoming universal friends
>   and devoted to the good of all the creatures.’

Mahabharata Santi Parva Section CCXLI

Another description of Moksha is given in Mahabharata:

> When men of knowledge, conversant with the rules of Yoga,
>   become as fixed as a stake of wood, and as immovable as a mountain,
>   then are they said to be in Yoga. When one does not hear, and smell,
>   and taste, and see; when one is not conscious of any touch; when one’s
>   mind becomes perfectly free from every purpose; when one is not
>   conscious of anything, when one cherishes no thought; when one becomes
>   like a piece of wood, then is one called by the wise to be in perfect
>   Yoga. At such a time one shines like a lamp that burns in a place
>   where there is no wind; at such a time one becomes freed even from
>   one’s subtle form, and perfectly united with Brahma. When one attains
>   to such progress, one has no longer to ascend or to fall among
>   intermediate beings. When persons like ourselves say that there has
>   been a complete identification of the Knower, the Known, and
>   Knowledge, then is the Yogin said to behold the Supreme Soul.
>
> Mahabharata Santi Parva Section CCCVII